# Please create SQL Server tag synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

At least the main one: [mssql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mssql) (12) --> [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)

Maybe also the version-specific ones? None of these exist yet, but I suspect they will get created eventually. Might as well prevent the madness now.

[mssql-2005](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mssql-2005) --> [sql-server-2005](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005)
[mssql-2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mssql-2008) --> [sql-server-2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008)

Comment: Sadly, I can't create the `[retag-request]` tag here on Meta -- need 150 rep. lol

Comment: Hey Jon, can you double check me and make sure I did the synonyms right?

Comment: @jcolebrand: Yep, that looks correct. (I assume you only proposed them so they could be checked.) Thanks.

Comment: Are there enough users with high enough rep to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created "sql-server-2012" tag but can't suggest synonyms for it yet.

Synonyms:

- sql-server-2011
- sqlserver2011
- sqlserver2012
- mssql2011
- mssql2012
- denali

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these got created, so adding an answer here so this does not show up as unanswered for us.